# Выгрузка проекта visual studio в gogs

Tags: visual-studio, git

Постараюсь объяснить ситуацию. Участвую в олимпиаде по программированию для школоты. Там проект в конце каждого дня нужно грузить в gogs, а я его сегодня впервые увидел. Объясните мне пню трухлявому: как мне выгружать этот проект в gogs? Мне требуются максимально простое решение желательно без всех этих консолей если такое вообще существует. P.S я описал эту ситуацию моему бывшему наставнику и он написал дословно следующие: "можешь в него грузить мышкой через ui. Либо через гит." Расшифруйте пожалуйста это сообщение.

Comment: Вам какой-то адресс выдавали где лежат репозитории/ Вы можете создать свои репозитории или подрозумевалось, что каждый из вас будет устанавливать свой сервер gogs на своем компьютере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gogs - это разновидность git сервера. Я так понимаю, что у Вас в школе установлен именно он.

1. **Вариант 1**:  Вы работаете с ним как с обычнымы удаленными репозиториями. Вам должны были огласить адресс сервера где лежат репозитории.
2. **Вариант 2**: Подрозумевается, что каждый школьник должен был установить на свой рабочий комп Gogs.

   - Скачиваете Gogs
   - Устанавливаете Gogs(см. доку на сайте)
   - Конфигурируете(см. доку на сайте).
   - Потом работаете как в Варианте 1.

Ваш наставник написал, что Вы можете сделать git push прямо из Visual Studio.(Team Explorer) или с помощью других Git инструментов, установленных на Вашем компьютере